# How do I access an ImageButton in a different class in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, class, findviewbyid

So Im new to **Android Studio** and I havn't been getting any help through Google. So my problem is that I'm trying to access an ImageButton from another class rather than just putting that method in the `MainActivity`.

My second question is, am I doing this the wrong way? How would you solve this without having to put that method of changing pictures in the MainActivity which I did before (it worked too but started to look messy).

So this is the `Player class`:

```
public class Player extends ActionBarActivity {

    public Player(){
    }
    public void changeThatPicture(int siffra){

        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.tarning);
        switch(siffra){
            case 1: imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.one); break;
            case 2: imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.two); break;
            case 3: imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.three); break;
            case 4: imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.four); break;
            case 5: imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.five); break;
            case 6: imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.six); break;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is from my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Player p1 = new Player();
    number = 1 + random.nextInt(6);
    p1.changeThatPicture(number);

    playGame();
}
```

Comment: You will need the context of the activity to properly retrieve views.  You could pass that into your Player class which can then load a view and allow you to manipulate it.

Comment: You also could simply return the value you need and set it there

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong here, from a programming point of view. There is no need for Player to extend ActionBarActivity. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this;

From MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.tarning)
    number = 1 + random.nextInt(6);
    Player.changeThatPicture(btn, number);

    playGame();
}
```

A Plain class, no need to extend activity it just add confusion and mess. The method is made static so you don't need to instantiate it to use the method.

```
public class Player  {

    public static void changeThatPicture(ImageButton imgBtn, int siffra) {
        switch(siffra){
            case 1: imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.one); break;
            case 2: imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.two); break;
            case 3: imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.three); break;
            case 4: imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.four); break;
            case 5: imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.five); break;
            case 6: imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.six); break;
        }
    }

}
```